# How to make ng-init "wait" until all libraries are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-api-client

I am using angularjs and have these ng-init calls being made in my partials:

```
<div ng-init="invited()">
```

In my controller, I have the invited call structured as follows. It has a gapi asynchronous call:

```
    $scope.invited = function () {

    gapi.client.conference.invited().
        execute(function(resp){
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                if (resp.error){
                    $log.error('There was an Error');
                }
                else {
                    $log.info("Success");
                    $scope.invitedHangouts = []
                    $scope.invitedHangout=[]
                    angular.forEach(resp.items, function(invitedHangout){
                        $scope.invitedHangouts.push(invitedHangout);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

};
```

The problem is that whenever I refresh the page with the partial above, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'invited' of undefined.

At this point the page is loaded. However, I noticed peculiar behavior that once I refresh the page, and then I get that TypeError, when I navigate away to a different page and then come back to the partial with the ng-init above, then it loads fine. It then outputs "Success" along with the rest of the correct information.

Why is it that when I refresh the page, I get the TypeError and then once I have refreshed the page, get the TypeError, navigate away from the page and then return to that page, that it executes fine?

I suspect that it is because it has not finished loading my backend server code - the gapi. The invited() from the gapi.client.conference.invited() is a function I have written for my server in python code.

From working with this problem so far, because it eventually executes the invited() function successfully after I navigate away and then return to that page, I am assuming it has something to do with the fact that my front-end is calling the back-end without it being initialized yet.

What is peculiar is that if my assumption is correct, why is it then, that when I misspell the front-end call to something non-existent in the backend (in effect imitating the fact that the front is calling the backend when it is not done loading) I get a totally different error? Shouldn't I get the same TypeError?

I misspell the gapi call as such:
gapi.client.conference.boomshakalaka(). boomshakalaka() is not in my backend python code.

At first when I refresh the page with this nonexistent function in the backend, I get the same error as above. Then when I navigate away and come back to the same page, I get a different type of error:
TypeError: gapi.client.conference.boomshakalaka is not a function

Before it was just a TypeError of undefined, now it is a TypeError of it not being a function.

How can it now know, that it is not a function? It could only know, if it has loaded the back end and realized that there is no such a function when trying to make the call. Shouldn't it do this from the initial page refresh too given that there is no existent function?

I think maybe it is caught somewhere in limbo between it having loaded this gapi.client.conference portions of the backend, but not yet having fully loaded everything to "know" that boomshakalaka is truly not there.

How can I then initialize this page with this gapi call, but make it wait until the backend is fully loaded? Again, I suspect it is my backend code not having loaded completely as when I navigate away from the page after a refresh and come back to it, that I get no such error. Everything then prints to the console successfully. It is only when I refresh that I get the TypeError.

Ideas?

Comment: shouldn't be using ng-init this way in the first place...read the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem area is **gapi.client.conference** while you might try to wrap in a **$timeout** over the existing code to give your script some time to get it initialized.

Dirty fix which might work but you should try to figure out why the gapi service is failing in first place. Perhaps do a callback when its ready instead of doing angular init.

```
$scope.invited = function () {
$timeout(function(){
  gapi.client.conference.invited().
        execute(function(resp){});
},200);
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks, the $timeout does help me further diagnose the problem. I just tried it out and it is a 50/50 shot of the gapi service succeeding during a refresh of the page. So there is something there in regards to the loading of the gapi.client.conference and it needing to "finish."

Though as charlietfl pointed out, and as I have suspected, I am using ng-init not as intended. 

I need to initialize the page with this gapi call. The docs say to initialize within the controller, so I remove the $scope.invited function body altogether and just leave the gapi. Still doesn't initialize correctly.

Comment: Oh and Abhi, P.S. I upvoted your answer, did you get points for that. I still don't have enough rep. points so it won't publicly change the upvote score. Just making sure you get credit.

Comment: And I'm looking into this router resolve as mentioned from charlietfl and I think that may be it. I just have to find more documentation on how to implement it. Not really understanding the AngularJS docs on coding it up, though it has something in line with my problem of waiting for an event to trigger/initialization. Thank you all for the input. At least this leads me somewhere to investigate into the matter further.